# Angular 4/5 - Instantiate service with dynamic configuration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, authentication, angular-services

I'm currently writing a library that exposes an `AuthModule`, which contains an `AuthService` for handling OAuth2 authentication using `oidc-client-js`. However, I would like the consuming application to specify the configuration for the OAuth client. I know I can pass in a configuration into the `forRoot` method of the `AuthModule`, like so:

```
AuthModule.forRoot({
    applicationNamespace: 'ConsumingApp',
    clientId: 'consuming.app'
});
```

In the `forRoot` method, I'd like to provide an instance of the service with the passed in config.

I've managed to hack it by just setting the passed in properties on the `window` object. I then use the references to `window.clientId` and `window.applicationNamespace` in the `AuthService`.

```
(window as any).applicationNamespace = authConfig.applicationNamespace;
(window as any).clientId = authConfig.clientId;
```

Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Really? No one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in the following way using an injection token.

**Step 1:** Create an `InjectionToken` for the configuration object that's passed in, like so:

```
export const AUTH_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<AuthConfig>('authConfig');
```

**Step 2:** Inject the token into the `AuthService` constructor

**Step 3:** Pass the configuration object into the forRoot function for your module

```
public static forRoot(authConfig: AuthConfig): ModuleWithProviders
```

**Step 4:** Use the passed in configuration as the value for the injection token

```
{ provide: AUTH_CONFIG, useValue: authConfig }
```